# Building JSON in a Grails app

Tags: json, grails

I'm using Grails 2.5.0 and want to build some JSON. It appears that there are two relevant builders available

- `groovy.json.JsonBuilder`
- `grails.web.JSONBuilder`

What are the differences between these two? Should I prefer one over the other (e.g. for performance reasons)?

Comment: Not sure, but the later is grails whilst the former is groovy, I would say that the later probably would support grails related things, such as convert Domain objects to JSON, whilst the former would work for groovy. Anyway you probably should take a look to https://grails.org/wiki/converters%20reference

Comment: I have been using the first one with Grails 2.5.0 to perform GET and POST requests and doing pretty good with it - extremely easy to construct heavy json constructs with composite properties and arrays with no problems. Can't comment on the second one.